# Kfserving -- Error When Defining storageUri

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow

I'm trying to deploy a very basic Sklearn model using Kfserving, here is the yaml file:

```
apiVersion: "serving.kubeflow.org/v1alpha2"
kind: "InferenceService"
metadata:
  name: "sklearn-iris"
spec:
  default:
    predictor:
      sklearn:
        storageUri: file://./storage_dir
```

Note that since our corporate environment doesn't have access to Google Cloud Storage, for now I just use one of my local folders as the `storageUri`, and I have the `model.joblib` stored in the folder.

After I deploy it with `kubectl apply -f sklearn.yaml -n kfserving-test`, I got the following error when inspecting  `kubectl describe  revision sklearn-iris-predictor-default-fj5qt -n kfserving-test`:

```
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2020-12-16T22:51:38Z
    Message:               The target is not receiving traffic.
    Reason:                NoTraffic
    Severity:              Info
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Active
    Last Transition Time:  2020-12-16T22:51:37Z
    Message:               Container failed with: [I 201216 22:50:07 storage:35] Copying contents of /mnt/models to local
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/sklearnserver/sklearnserver/__main__.py", line 33, in <module>
    model.load()
  File "/sklearnserver/sklearnserver/model.py", line 36, in load
    model_file = next(path for path in paths if os.path.exists(path))
StopIteration

    Reason:                ExitCode1
    Status:                False
    Type:                  ContainerHealthy
    Last Transition Time:  2020-12-16T22:51:38Z
    Message:               Initial scale was never achieved
    Reason:                ProgressDeadlineExceeded
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
    Last Transition Time:  2020-12-16T22:51:38Z
    Message:               Initial scale was never achieved
    Reason:                ProgressDeadlineExceeded
    Status:                False
    Type:                  ResourcesAvailable
  Container Statuses:
    Image Digest:       gcr.docker.prod.walmart.com/kfserving/sklearnserver@sha256:d2553d3f2a6ba7b50736028e6dbdfb35e90ca40ee7aa5cbe0e0b66fec1695f16
    Name:               kfserving-container
  Image Digest:         gcr.docker.prod.walmart.com/kfserving/sklearnserver@sha256:d2553d3f2a6ba7b50736028e6dbdfb35e90ca40ee7aa5cbe0e0b66fec1695f16
  Log URL:              http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/knative-monitoring/services/kibana-logging/proxy/app/kibana#/discover?_a=(query:(match:(kubernetes.labels.knative-dev%2FrevisionUID:(query:'e6fee737-b9b8-4091-96a5-660dbf4082f8',type:phrase))))
  Observed Generation:  1
  Service Name:         sklearn-iris-predictor-default-fj5qt
Events:
  Type     Reason         Age    From                 Message
  ----     ------         ----   ----                 -------
  Warning  InternalError  2m16s  revision-controller  failed to update deployment "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-fj5qt-deployment": Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.apps "sklearn-iris-predictor-default-fj5qt-deployment": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again
```

The exception looks like it failed to load/transfer the model files, and I'm wondering I did something wrong with the `storageUri` argument. It is supposed to be the relative path of the model file, right? (Reference: https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/blob/master/python/kfserving/docs/V1alpha2SKLearnSpec.md)

Comment: What version of Kubernetes and Kfserving are you using ? Did you take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65332452/kfserving-error-when-defining-storageuri  ?

Comment: I'm following this script here to install the components: `https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/blob/master/hack/quick_install.sh`, the only difference is the cluster is not built from Minikube: `ISTIO_VERSION=1.6.2`,`KNATIVE_VERSION=v0.18.0`, `KFSERVING_VERSION=v0.4.1`.  For Kubernetes version:`Client Version:1.19.4, Server Version: 1.17.11`. Also the link you provided linked back to this page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KFServing is injecting a second container in the pod of the predictor, SKLearn in your case, which is called `storage_initializer`. Its role is to download and copy of the model file from the `storageUri` to a location in the pod to offload the predictor from such a task.

Using the `file://` in the `storageUri` can be comfortable for tests when building KFServing, but it would require the pod to have the file already mounted locally.

If you don't have access to a cloud-based storage like `gs://` and `s3://`, you can use one of the alternative solutions like `uri://` or `pvc://`, serving the model file from your local kubernetes cluster. You can find [examples here](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/tree/master/docs/samples/storage).